# Android Google Checkout Alternative

Tags: android, google-checkout, in-app-billing

I have to create an application where a user makes a deal and then gives me (the owner of the application) a certain amount of money for the deel to be made available to the rest of the world. I was thinking of achieving this through Google Checkout, but I stumbled upon Android in app billing sdk. My question is, is it possible to use in app billing in my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The google in app billing works only officially with receivables (AFAIK) i.e. The most effective way i could see you doing this is to make the deal, then charge for an item called for example ("Transaction fee" / "Deal fee") and then the app runs as normal.

It's not reccomended that you start using your own payment system, purely if not anything else, support could drop at any minute and your app starts breaking the ToS

Comment: But the would'nt I have to make a lot of these items? since the product Id has to be different also?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer :) We can use in app billing with Unmanaged products :)